# Error: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage, system.drawing.imaging

I get this error. Here is the code:

```
    Image image;
    BitmapImage BmpImg;
    MemoryStream ms;

    public void Convert()
    {
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        BmpImg = new BitmapImage();
        BmpImg.BeginInit();
        BmpImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
        BmpImg.EndInit();
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {     
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { Image.Source = BmpImg; }));
    }
```

How to convert a System.Drawing.Image to BitmapImage and display the same on wpf?

Comment: Don't do it on a thread other than the UI thread.

Comment: Also, you don't have to create another memory stream, just do `ms.Position = 0;` and you can reuse the existing one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BmpImg` is created on background thread. **You cannot bind to `Image Source DP` object which is created on thread other than UI thread.**

Since you are using `Dispatcher`, i assume you now how to delegate stuff on UI thread.

So all you need to do is put the creation of `BmpImg` on UI thread as well via Dispatcher.

You can get UI dispatcher like this as well - `App.Current.Dispatcher`.

**OR**

As @Clemens suggested in comments, if you call `Freeze()` on BitmapImage instance, you can access it across threads.

```
BmpImg.Freeze()
```

Comment: Not entirely true. It would work after calling `BmpImg.Freeze()`.

Comment: Yeah it will but since OP haven't call `Freeze` on it, so i suggested this but true I will update in answer. Thanks!